# Invoking Batch Apex in Update Trigger

Tags: trigger

I have written before update trigger on an object. In that trigger I am invoking batch Apex to update the same object records but in apexjob am getting error like this

> First error: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id a0A9000000V5kLGEAZ; >First error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, CandidateUpdate: execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.AsyncException: Database.executeBatch cannot be called from...

What should I do to avoid this error?

Comment: Can you include the code that you are having difficulties with?

Answer (score 6):

You can't perform an update from a before trigger or call anything that invokes an update. You need make your trigger an After Update.

Answer (score 2):

Move the batch call to after insert.

You will have to write some logic to avoid recursive updates on record. Trigger updates record -> batch updates record in same object -> again trigger fires and it loops till hitting limit.

Also be careful while calling batch class from trigger. If same batch is in queue more than 5 times, code will fail with "Maximum concurrent batches exceeded" exception. So if five users are updating records at the same time, you may hit this limit.